# channel name in asterisk

Tags: asterisk, channel

I'm using Asterisk 11. I have a problem to get channel name when I attempt to call-out.
Usually, I can get the channel name when the called party picks up his/her phone. But now,  I would like to get the channel name right after I dial out. I can see it on the screen like this:

```
Called SIP/7146991234@64.195.139.88
- SIP/64.195.139.88-00000001 is ringing
-- SIP/64.195.139.88-00000001 is making progress passing it to SIP/8001-00000000
```

I know that the channel name is : "SIP/64.195.139.88-00000001",
but I don't know how to get it from coding or any other ways.
Please help me.
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

You can get the name of the outbound channel in Asterisk 11 using a [Pre-Dial Handler](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Pre-Dial+Handlers) on the called channel.

```
[default]    
exten => pre_dial_handler,1,NoOp()
 same => n,Verbose(1, Channel is ${CHANNEL})
 same => n,Return()

exten => dial_example,1,NoOp()
 same => n,Dial(SIP/alice,,b(default^pre_dial_handler^1)
```

This will execute the subroutine pre_dial_handler on channel SIP/alice-XXXXXXXX, as opposed to whatever channel is actually performing the dial operation. The subroutine is executed on the outbound channel immediately after creation but before any operation is taken on it, such as making a call attempt.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get channel name of outbound channel in dialplan

Reason: it not created yet at that moment.

But you can get it by external application by checking variables BRDIGEDPEERNAME or listnen event.

Also you can get both channels in cmd_dial internal macro(M param)

Comment: thank you Arheops, The cmd Dial with M option only get the channel name after the called party answered. Can you please show me how to use external application to get channel name on BRDIGEDPEERNAME variable or listen event? Thank you!

Comment: No, i can't "show" how to develop app. See AMI/events, ringing event.

Comment: That isn't correct for Asterisk 11. As I noted in my answer, in that version of Asterisk you have pre-dial handlers, which do exactly what the OP wanted.

Comment: Thanks Matt! using pre-dial is the best way!